# Is it possible to specify MarkLogic Developer license when doing automated CloudFormation deployment?

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to set up an automated deployment of a MarkLogic cluster to AWS using MarkLogic's provided AMI and ansible.  Everything works great, but I can't figure out how to specify that I want a developer license.

If I don't specify the Licensee parameter, it sets up a "pay by the hour" Enterprise license.

I know I can go to the server after the deployment to request a Developer license.  I'm trying to do this without human interaction.  The [MarkLogic AMI documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/CloudFormation#id_44259) does not provide the details

Is there a way to start the cluster without the Enterprise license, or to specify that I want to spin it up with a Developer license?

Answer (score 0):

It is the AMI itself not any license you supply that determines if it is using the 'paid by the hour' marketplace AMI or some other one.
Edit your copy of the cloud formation template and replace the AMI in it (for your region) with the appropriate AMI here   https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B072Z536VB
Then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not correct.  Both the Developer and Enterprise Essentials versions use the same AMI template.  See http://developer.marklogic.com/products/cloud/aws

If you put license information in it, it works with your own license.  If you leave it blank, you get the pay by the hour version.  Both allow you to later change to a developer license.